# Git doesn't see new files

Tags: git

I have a folder `dotfiles` where I keep my configuration files like `.vimrc`. Now in my current version on the master there is an empty folder `dotfiles/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized/`
I wanted to add files to this folder (so that the solarized color scheme actually works), so I went to the `bundle directory` and cloned the  solarized github project

```
$ cd dotfiles/.vim/bundle
$ git clone git://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git
```

Now, the folder `bundle/vim-colors-solarized` is actually filled with files. Weirdly, when I go back to the `dotfiles` folder and ask for `git status` it says that everything is up to date with the master branch and that there is nothing to commit.

Is this because I cloned a git project in stead of actually copying those files?

Comment: If `git status` doesn't throw an error when run in `dotfiles/`, it means that you have (at least) one Git repository (`vim-colors-solarized`) nested inside another (`dotfiles`?). In that case, running `git status` outside the root folder of the nested Git repo will not tell you anything about modified files in that repo.

Comment: @Jubobs - does git automatically ignore nested repos or something? I would have guessed that it would show the nested .git directory (along with everything else) as something to add.

Comment: @DavidDeutsch See VonC's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this because I cloned a git project in stead of actually copying those files?

Yes, a `git status` won't show the status of a nested git repo.

If you want to actually commit a reference to github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git, you need to add it as a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)** with [`git submodule add`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).

```
git submodule add -- https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git dotfiles/.vim/bundle/vim-colors-solarized
```

Once added and initialized (`git submodule update --init`), you will add and commit the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)) of the SHA1 of the subrepo you have checked out.

Note that by default, `git status` only mention the global state ("dirty" or "new commits" or ...) of a submodule, not the exact modified files within said submodule repo.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether **.vim/** directory is listed in .gitignore file in **dotfiles/** directory.

Comment: That would be a good tip in general, but not in this case, where there is a Git repo nested inside another.